# nothing inserted error: column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data from a form into table in a MySQL database. I have tried all i could to ensure that i entered the right value without leaving any value out but it still returns an error "nothing inserted error: column count doesn't match value count at row 1".

The code for my insert is:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO athletes (Surname, Name, Second_Name, Date_Of_Birth, Gender, Club, Rank, Country_Obtained, Date_Joined, Postal_Address, Physical_Address, Contact_Number, National_ID_Passport_Number)

VALUES

('$_POST[sur]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[second]','$_POST[dob]','$_POST[gender]','$_POST[club]','$_POST[rank]','$_POST[co]','$_POST[djoined]','$_POST[pa]','$_POST[pha]','$_POST[cn]''$_POST[nid]')";
```

Please let me know if this is not enough to provide more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: syntax error, missing comma (,) between these variables '$_POST[cn]''$_POST[nid]'

Comment: This code is just too inviting for Little Bobby Tables [http://xkcd.com/327/](http://xkcd.com/327/). (But, there's no need to be concerned with SQL injection vulnerabilities until much later, until after we get a bunch of vulnerable code working.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last line you are missing a `,`

```
,'$_POST[cn]''$_POST[nid]')
             <--Here
```

Comment: thank you so much. I really thought i had gone through it carefully. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use it You have missed `,` between `$_POST[cn]''$_POST[nid]`  in query last line

```
$sql="INSERT INTO athletes (Surname, Name, Second_Name, Date_Of_Birth, Gender, Club, Rank, Country_Obtained, Date_Joined, Postal_Address, Physical_Address, Contact_Number, National_ID_Passport_Number) 
VALUES ('$_POST[sur]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[second]','$_POST[dob]','$_POST[gender]','$_POST[club]','$_POST[rank]','$_POST[co]','$_POST[djoined]','$_POST[pa]','$_POST[pha]','$_POST[cn]','$_POST[nid]')";
```